# NFS share mounting issue

Tags: centos, permissions, nfs, fstab

I have exported a handful of shares on my Synology - e.g. `/volume2/Home_Data/Downloads`

On my CentOS7 box I would like to mount this and have it available for all users of the system.

This works fine when I mounted to `/mnt/nfs/`

```
/etc/fstab entry

diskstation.davis.local:/volume2/Home_Data/     /mnt/nfs/      nfs4    user,nfsvers=4,nosuid,bg,noexec 0       0
```

However, I need it mounted to `/mnt/nfs/downloads`. When mounted here only root has the share mounted, other users cannot see it.

```
/etc/fstab entry

diskstation.davis.local:/volume2/Home_Data/     /mnt/nfs/downloads      nfs4    user,nfsvers=4,nosuid,bg,noexec 0       0
```

I thought it could be a perms issue, but the perms on `/mnt/nfs` & `/mnt/nfs/downloads` are the same.

Perms:

```
/mnt/:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root   26 Dec 15 12:28 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root root 4096 Dec 15 12:02 ..
drwx------.  6 root root   64 Dec 15 12:38 nfs
drwx------.  2 root root    6 Dec  3 11:30 tmp

/mnt/nfs/:
total 0
drwx------. 6 root root 64 Dec 15 12:38 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 26 Dec 15 12:28 ..
drwx------. 3 root root 18 Dec 15 12:37 downloads
```

Any ideas what I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go into the synology control panel and make sure NFS share is checked.  And then prior to mounting it in CentOS, do a `chmod -R 777 /mnt` to make everything under `/mnt` read-write-execute for all.  I have a few synology boxes and have them NFS mounted to my linux systems and they work well.  This is for NFSv3.

And if you cannot get it to work from the web browser log in to the synology, then open up an SSH connection to the Synology and use putty.exe.  from here you can view the synology operating system, which is linux based and will look very familiar, and then you can dive deeper into how NFS-server is working on the synology box.

Comment: Thanks the permissions on my subfolders under /mnt/nfs were causing the issue. I knew it had to be something simple.